# 2D shape optimization through genetic algorithms

Tags: geometry, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I just recently started learning about genetic algorithms and am now trying to implement them in 2D shape optimization in physics simulaiton. The simulation produces a single scalar for each shape. (I guess this is kind of similar to boxcar2d http://boxcar2d.com/)

The 2D shapes are actually the union of several 2D "sub shapes." Each subshape is stored as an list of angles/radii. The 2D shape is then stored as a list of subshape lists. This serves as my chromosone right now.

Right now for fitness, I will probably use the scalar the simulation produced. My question is, how should I go about the selection and reproduction process? Would tournament be more appropriate, or would I want to use truncation in combination with the proportional selection? Also, how do you find a good mutation rate/population size, etc

sorry for so many questions but thanks in advance. I just don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my point of view the best way is to use *adaptive reproduction strategy* during evolution: at the first steps (let name it - "the first phase of calculations") you might set *high mutation probability*, at this phase you should find enough good solution. At the "second phase" of algorithm you might set *decreasing of mutation probability* every few steps - at this phase you should improve your solution. But sometimes in  my practice I've *noticed degradation of population during second phase of optimization* (when each chromosome is strongly similar to other) - which effects with extremly slowing down of optimization pperformance, *so my solution was to improve algorithm with high valued mutation random perturbations* and it helps.

Also I'll advice you to read about **differential evolution algorithm** - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_evolution. As for me it's performance is much more faster than genetic algorithm.